# Submit form to 2 different action page

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have a form that can submit to two different action pages based on a select box.

Meaning if I select in the select box `Products`, the action would be `products.html`, and if I select `Users`, the action would be `users.html`

I have found many examples that have two submit buttons, but I need only one submit button.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use jQuery for that ...

if selected value equals something

set form attribute action to the other thing not initial action

this is pseudo code of course ..

here is a working solution :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectList").change(function(){
        if($('#selectList').val() == 1){
        $("#yourform").attr("action","secondaryaction");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="dummy" id="selectList">
<option value="0">foo</option>
<option value="1">bar</option>
</select>

<form id="yourform" action="primaryaction">
bla bla
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, just add the submit button :D

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (assuming a form named "myForm"):

```
document.myForm.onsubmit = function() {
    if (this.mySelector.value == 'products') {
        this.action = 'products.html';
    }
    // the "else" isn't necessary: leave it at "users.html" as a default.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

read about new attributes 
Attributes for form submission that may be specified on submit buttons. The attributes are: formaction, formenctype, formmethod, formnovalidate, and formtarget

Works in IE >= 11

my example for will be demonstrated point :

```
<form action="1.php">
  <input type="text" >
  <button value="go"> GOOOOOOOOOOOO</button>
 <button value="go" formaction="2.php"> DONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOO</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(condition==products)
document.forms[0].action = 'products.html;
else
document.forms[0].action = 'users.html;
```