# Jquery attach show event to select option

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a select form element with 5 options.  If option 2 is selected I want to display another form input box (this has a style of display:none initially).  How can I attach an event to option 2 so that whenever it is selected the input box is shown otherwise it is hidden.  I have this currently but this does not handle is option 2 is already selected when the page loads

```
$('#type').change(function(){
        var typeSelected = $(this).val();
        if (typeSelected == 2) {
            $('#extraInput').show();
        }
    });
```

I know I could add another bit of code which checks what is selected on page load but wondered if there was a neater way of doing this. Also something that could handle the hiding of the input box if option 2 is not selected at the start as currently I have just hard-coded style="display:none" onto the input box but I would prefer this to be dynamic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code must look like this: 
**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ezolu4/edit

```
$(function() {

      $('#type').change(function() {
            var typeSelected = $(this).val();

            if (typeSelected == 2) {
                $('#extraInput').fadeIn(200);
            } else {
          $('#extraInput').fadeOut(200);
          }
        }).change();
    });
```

Ops.. I have the solution for you!

Comment: thanks it worked. just a question, what is the purpose of $(function() { at the beginning of the code?  Also is the .change(); at the end of the code just used to trigger a change on the type object automatically just the same as the trigger event in the above answer does?

Comment: $(function () {}); is just like DOM ready! $(document).reday(function(){});

it tell the script that when page load must execute something!

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna try :

```
  $('#type').change(function(){
            var typeSelected = $(this).val();
            if (typeSelected == 2) {
                $('#extraInput').show();
            }
            else{
            $('#extraInput').hide();
            }
        });
```

How does your html looks like `<option>Option name</option>` or

```
<option value="0">Option name</option>
```

Refer to my previous answer :

[Submit form to 2 different action page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446188/submit-form-to-2-different-action-page/2446212#2446212)

**You need to have option value in order to compare which option you selected.**

Comment: <option value="0">Option name</option>

Answer (score 2):

What if you try `$('#type').trigger('change');` on page load?
Does that solve the problem?

```
$('#type').trigger('change');
$('#type').change(function(){
    var typeSelected = $(this).val();
    if (typeSelected == 2) {
        $('#extraInput').show();
    } else {
        $('#extraInput').hide();
    }
});
```