# How to POST to 2 pages by help of button or link in HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Hey Friends
i am having one forms and two button, and some text fields,what i need it if i click button 1 then the details in the text box should be POST to Page1.php if i click Button2 the details in the text box should be POST to Page2.php, i am having 8 text boxes to do the in form, how can i do that?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446188/submit-form-to-2-different-action-page/2446212#2446212

Comment: You don't need that. One page is enough. Especially if there is 8 text boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose your button one id is `btn1` and second has `btn2` and form name is `frm`, you can do something like this:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

btn1.onclick = function(){
  document.forms['frm'].action = 'page1.php'
  document.forms['frm'].submit(); // submit the form
};

btn2.onclick = function(){
  document.forms['frm'].action = 'page2.php'
  document.forms['frm'].submit(); // submit the form
};
```

Comment: @Alex Mathew: Yeah that is it.

Comment: how can i use this in case of Links in <a href ??

Comment: @Alex: You need to give the ids to them too like I told and place `return false;` below `document.forms['frm'].submit();`

Answer (score 2):

A PHP solution would be:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
  <input name='inputText' /><br />
  <button value='1' name='whichOption'></button><br />
  <button value='2' name='whichOption'></button><br />
</form>
```

At the top of the page this form is in, put this:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['whichOption']) {
    switch($_POST['whichOption']) {
      case 1: /* do something */ break;
      case 2: /* do something else */ break;
    }
  }
?>
```

"something" is an include, a session variable set, or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" value="page1" onclick="this.form.action='Page1.php'; this.form.submit();" />
<input type="button" value="page2" onclick="this.form.action='Page2.php'; this.form.submit();" />
```

Comment: You should avoid inline javascript when possible and go unobstrusive :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: My pragmatism says I should not write additional functions for the trivial situations like this :)

Comment: @Donatas Olsevičius: Yeah that looks faster and easier ;)

Comment: your pragmatism should tell you never do such stupid things like 2 action forms.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: could you please show at least one of my projects with 2 action forms? I can't.

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104213/how-to-post-to-2-pages-by-help-of-button-or-link-in-html/4104235#4104235

Comment: That's just the answer to the question posted by Alex Mathew. If he wants different submits, he gets it.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You wrote it. It wonders me though, why everyone is writing stupid answers here. Stupid question is not an excuse.

Answer (score 0):

```
Html:
<input id="Button1" value="Button1" type="button" /><br />
<input id="Button2" value="Button2" type="button" /><br />
<textarea id="TextBox1" cols="40" rows="5"><br />
<textarea id="TextBox2" cols="40" rows="5">
```

jQuery:

```
function PostToPage(DOOMid,uri) {
    var vDOOMEl = $("#" + DOOMid);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: uri,
        data: ({text : vDOOMEl.innerHTML}),
        success: function() {},
        dataType: "html"
    });
}

function init() {

    $('#Button1').click(function(e){
        PostToPage('TextBox1','Page1.php');
    });

    $('#Button2').click(function(e){
        PostToPage('TextBox2','Page2.php');
    });
}

window.onload=init;
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    //do something with $_POST['text'];
?>
```

You must download [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), and use it for this solution

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the same page? When I need multiple submit alternatives I simply use submit buttons with different names:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit-save" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="submit-delete" value="Delete" />
```

When I need to know what action it is, I just check which data is sent:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-save']))
{
   //Do something
}
elseif(isset($_POST['submit-delete']))
{
   //Do something else
}
```