# Submit One form to 2 apis

Tags: forms, aweber

I'm trying to create a form that will submit data to 2 different API's based on a check box and one submit button.

Basically, I'm working on creating a form that allows a site vistor to register for a gotomeeting event. That's the main function of the form. Secondary to that, I want to include a check box that would allow the user to subscribe to an email list.

If the user leaves the checkbox unchecked - he or she would simply be signing up for the event via GTMeeting. If he or she checked the box, that means they register for the event and want to subscribe.

In case 2, The user data needs to be passed separately to Aweber (email client of choice here) and GoToMeeting.

I've created separate forms to handle these tasks separately - and with success. But I cannot figure out how to make the 2 post calls with just one submit button.

I read this post here from ant which seems like it should work: [Submit form to 2 different action page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446188/submit-form-to-2-different-action-page)

can anyone confirm this for me - in theory?

Thanks.

Craig

Comment: That answer only allow you to choose a different action URL instead of submitting the form to two different URLs at the same time (this would need Ajax).

Comment: Thanks Jay.Can you point me to something that would accomplish the two api action with one submit button?